# Displaying a value as an image in vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, gridview

In my aspx page I have a gridview which displays the value from my database as "`*`". So if a value in my database table is 5, it will be displayed as "`*****`" in the gridview.

code in aspx:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rating" SortExpression="Rating">
              <ItemTemplate><h1><%# getrating(Eval("Rating"))%></h1></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

code in aspx.vb

```
Protected Function getrating(ByVal rate As Integer)
        Dim retval As String
        retval = ""
        For i = 1 To rate
            retval = retval + "*"
        Next
        Return retval
    End Function
```

What I want to do is change that "`*`" to a picture, ie star.jpg, so in the gridview it will display the image star.jpg instead of "`*`".

Any idea on how to do this please? Using  MS visual studio 2010

Comment: Have a look at my answer on this similar question recently: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8502496/284240

Comment: In your example of 5 being `*****` do you want that to be a single image or five instances of the star.jpg image? Also what is the valid range? I assume 1 to 5 or 1 to 10 (ie a relatively limited set) rather than being 1 to ten billion or something like that...

Comment: @Chris  five instances of the star.jpg image and the range depends on the value in the database, which has been set to 1 to 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just do something like the following:

```
retval = retval + "<img src=""star.jpg"" alt=""*"">"
```

You may need some styling to put them all on the same line (float:left should do) but I forget offhand whether that is necessary.

The principle of this is obviously pretty basic. In the outputted HTML you will just have an image tag where before you had a *. A neater way to do it might be to have five images for one to five and then have something like:

```
Protected Function getrating(ByVal rate As Integer)
    Dim retval As String
    retval = String.Format("<img src=""Star{0}.jpg"" alt=""{0} stars"">", rate)
    Return retval
End Function
```

This will output an image tag pointing to any of Star1 to Star5. This is nicer in some ways because it allows better control over how they look as well as allowing you to make five identical sized images and know that the space used will always be the same.

Comment: @RayClark: Don't forget to accept the answer if you are happy that it is the correct one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation using CSS - http://www.thebroth.com/blog/119/css-rating-stars - does require additional divs and two images to create effect but seems to be a neat solution.