# Can I replace an asp:GridView value with an image?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, boundfield

I have an asp:GridView which includes many BoundField's.  One of the fields, called 'status' shows a value of either 1, 2 or 3 (which is got from a column in the database, obviously).

Is there a way I can replace these numbers with images instead?

i.e.

```
1 = <img src="img1.png" />
2 = <img src="img2.png" />
3 = <img src="img3.png" />
```

[image: Change Values to Images]

Comment: It looks similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502496/displaying-different-pictures-in-gridview-depending-on-the-data

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a template field you can do something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image" >
  <ItemTemplate >            
  <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/images/img" &  Eval("Status") & ".png" %>'
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Im guessing your code is using VB.  For C#, its <%# "~/images/img" + Eval("Status") + ".png" %>

Comment: Your welcome, don't forget to accept the solution as the correct answer.